# rails app not serving assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2

I am deploying in EC2 instance. I am using develoment and staging environments. On changing public IP to elastic IP I found my assets(stylesheets, images and javascript) are not loaded in both the environments. When I have public IP everything worked fine. Assets are precompiled with capistrano3 in both the environments.I can find files under public/assets. But the UI does not show up any styles and images. What can I do to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a problem with how Rails accesses the assets

---

**Assets**

I'd look at implementing the [asset_host](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets) feature:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "your_cdn"
```

Without knowing your CDN URL structure, I can't recommend any references. I would recommend you update the answer with the `<head>` section of your rendered HTML (to show us where Rails thinks the assets are)